# How I print UTF-8 characters C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding

How I print [these UTF-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122018/does-this-program-show-the-four-card-suits-on-all-standard-ish-systems) in C++?

Comment: depends on what font you use, whether it's unix or windows, whether you are writing a console or a GUI api.

Comment: preferably cross platform console

Comment: These characters aren't part of the ASCII character set, which means you have to select a font that contains them before you can print them.  There is no cross platform way to select fonts for console apps.  I don't think you can do it at all on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you know it is possible because your browser could render them.  On Windows you can use the charmap.exe applet to discover their Unicode code points:

- ♠ = 0x2660
- ♣ = 0x2663
- ♥ = 0x2665
- ♦ = 0x2666

The challenge is to get a C/C++ program to display them.  That's not going to be possible in any kind of non-platform specific way unless you use a cross-platform UI library like Qt or wxWidgets.  In a Windows GUI program you can do it like this in the WM_PAINT message handler:

```
  case WM_PAINT: {
      hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
      HFONT hFont = CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Arial Unicode MS");
      HGDIOBJ oldFont = SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
      RECT rc = {0, 0, 666, 16};
      DrawTextEx(hdc, L"\x2660\x2663\x2665\x2666", -1, &rc, DT_LEFT, 0);
      SelectObject(hdc, oldFont);
      DeleteObject(hFont);
      EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just output the appropriate bytes to your terminal, and **make sure the terminal is using a UTF-8 encoding** to display your data. C++ itself is relatively UTF8-agnostic. It's just an array of uint_8's.

(Unless you want to use some sort of character-oriented operations on strings with UTF-8. Then you need to use UTF-8 manipulation functions, instead of array indexes and the normal string manipulation routines.)

e.g. `sprintf("%c%c%c\n", 0xE2, 0x99, 0xA0);`

Answer (score 0):

In C++: 
  std::wcout << L"wstr [" << wstr << L']' << std::endl;

In C:
   printf("%ls\n\n",wstr);

Comment: wchar_t isn't guaranteed to be UTF-16.  It's certainly not going to be UTF-8.