# formatting output of booleans c++

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, boolean, output

I am a begginner at programming in c++ and I would like to know if there is a way you can change the output of boolean variables to low level graphics in the terminal (linux). To Display for example a small circle for **true** and a small square for **false**.

I am needing to display an array of booleans in terms of small symbols such as the example above as the output for a project, any suggestions on the best way to impliment this function if what I have asked is not possible?

Comment: Probably related: [How I print UTF-8 characters C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2122194), [How to print Unicode character in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12015571), [c++, cout and UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6953847), etc. Also see [utf8 character for circle and square](https://www.google.com/search?q=utf8+character+for+circle+and+square) for the code points.

Comment: `std::cout << (condition?'☐':'⚪') << std::endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print unicode Symbols using `std::wcout`. E.g. `"\u2605"` will print a star.

So you can write something like

```
std::wcout<< (myBool) ? "\u2605" : "\u25CF" <<std::endl;
```

This will print a star if `myBool` is `true` or a circle if `false`

You can find many tables of Unicode characters online, e.g. here: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/